# Is uncompressed transaction log file restore process faster then compressed in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, log-shipping

I am writing process to ship transaction log files from production SQL server to Read Only SQL Server. I am compressing transaction log in source DB, coping file to destination and restoring into Read Only instance. I do this in hourly bases.
Restoring log file in Read Only instance takes too long.
I wonder, if I use uncompressed transaction log, will restoring process faster?

Comment: Why wonder? Just try it.

Comment: Do not want to experiment in production environment, asking maybe someone already did and can share experience.